# Are timestamps the same as datetimes in mysql?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have a mysql database which stores timestamps but when I see it in phpmyadmin it shows it as date times and I would like to know why.

I don't think datetimes are the same as timestamps but...
Could it cause bigger storage needs because of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` are not the same datatypes although both are used to store date and time informations [(1)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html).

> [The] range for `DATETIME` values is '1000-01-01 00:00:00.000000' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999', and the range for `TIMESTAMP` values is
>   '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' to '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999'.
>
> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for
>   storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.

But beware, using TIMESTAMP might lead to unexpected results, because

> If you store a TIMESTAMP value, and then change the time zone and
>   retrieve the value, the retrieved value is different from the value
>   you stored. This occurs because the same time zone was not used for
>   conversion in both directions.

Since MySQL 5.6.4, 
`TIMESTAMP` need 4 Bytes + fractional seconds storage,
`DATETIME` needs 5 Bytes  + fractional seconds storage [(2)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-date-time).

You should use `TIMESTAMP` to store time information which is related to a time zone (which is the general case) - e.g. Business events. If you want to store a date which has no relation to a time zone - e.g. Birthdays - you can use `DATETIME`.

For more information see the [MySQL Spec](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information, It helped me a lot.